# Ubuntu 15.04 failed to boot, stuck at purple screen after trying to upgrade to 16.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 15.04, uefi

There are many threads related to this, but I am not able to find a solution specific to my problem.

Booting stuck at purple screen.

What exactly happened?
I was trying to update from 15.04 to 16.04 LTS using a bootable usb. I selected the option 'Upgrade ubuntu'. But when I was selecting keyboard layout, it said something like /boot/efi failed you can continue or go back. I selected go back and aborted the installation.

All disk partitions are fine as I am able to use them after mounting using a bootable usb. Bootloader is also working fine.
I tried to install ubuntu again, but now it is not detecting already installed ubuntu. Please help. I don't want to lose my installed programs.

Comment: Please take into consideration that updating from 15.04 directly to 16.04 is not a supported upgrade path.

Comment: @Bruni But I got option to upgrade when I was trying to install 16.04 using a bootable usb.

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that `/boot/efi` (you [EFI System Partition (ESP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition) has a damaged filesystem. This often happens when dual-booting with Windows 8 or later if the Windows Fast Startup and Hibernation options are enabled. Disabling them is covered [here](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html) and [here,](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2859-hibernate-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html) respectively. Note that if you disable these filesystem-damaging features, you may need to run `dosfsck` (from Linux) or `CHKDSK` (from Windows) on the ESP to correct any lingering problems. In extreme cases, it's necessary to do a file-level backup of the ESP (with `rsync`, `cp`, `tar`, or a similar file-level tool), create a fresh FAT32 filesystem on it, and then restore the backed-up files. This in turn may require updating the "UUID" (really a serial number) for the ESP in `/etc/fstab`.

If disabling Fast Startup and Hibernate doesn't help, please run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/). This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. This will give us more details about your configuration.

Comment: After mounting my / partition, I noticed that some directories are missing like '/usr' and '/var/log' so as a last option I backed up all my data and installed a fresh 16.04.1 LTS. Thanks anyways.